# How to Return Users on a Certain Day Who Performed an Action Along with Location SQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas

Sorry for the title, I wasn't sure what to call it. I'm looking for SQL (preferred) or Pandas that can take me from where I am. I'm trying to find how to get users who performed a given action on a certain day, but also include some information about them

In my user table I have:

```
userid, country, ...
1,      a
2,      b
3,      a
4,      a
```

I also have an events table that tracks events of the user

```
userid,    date,    event
1,         1/1/15   login
2,         1/1/15   login
3,         1/1/15   view
1,         1/1/15   view
```

I want to be able to either return a table that includes distinct users that login during that day and include country or get a count of the number of users who logged in each day by country.

I have done:

```
select date(events.date), events.userid, users.language
from events
join users
on
users.userid = events.userid  
where events.date > '2015-01-15' and events.date < '2015-01-17'
AND events.event LIKE %%%%LOGIN%%%%'
```

But this of course doesn't give me distinct users

```
2015-01-15  1   a
2015-01-15  1   a
2015-01-15  1   a
```

...

Comment: Are you asking for SQL code or pandas code to achieve what you want?

Comment: SQL preferred, Pandas from where I am is ok though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a small demo in SQLFiddler for you.

If you need the Users and the Country in a date range, you can use the following query:

```
-- USERs and Country by Date  
  select date(events.date), 
         events.userid, 
         users.country
    from events
    join users
      on users.userid = events.userid  
   where events.date >= '2015-01-01' and events.date < '2015-01-02'
     and events.event LIKE '%login%'
group by date(events.date), 
         events.userid, 
         users.country
```

If you need to count the number of user per country that logged in a date range you can uses something like this:

```
-- Country and Number of Users by Date  
  select date(events.date), 
         users.country,
         count(distinct events.userid) number_of_users
    from events
    join users
      on users.userid = events.userid  
   where events.date >= '2015-01-01' and events.date < '2015-01-02'
     and events.event LIKE '%login%'
group by date(events.date), 
         users.country
```

Comment: typos are always there to kill our ego :) Feel free to mark this as solution ;)

Comment: how about instead of counting it for each day, we only count it once over the range?

Comment: Then remove the date from the select and the group by